# HTTP post request in Python

Tags: python, aiohttp

I started to work with aiohttp. 
In order to make an HTTP POST request, after the following code was successful:

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get('http://httpbin.org/get') as resp:
        print(resp.status)
        print(await resp.text())
```

I used ClientSession.post() coroutine:

session.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data=b'data')

Python answered that the name session is not defined. What's wrong with this script?

Comment: can you share your code for post

Comment: post the whole code which is not working

Comment: Hope you are new here. Please refer [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question.

Comment: are you adding session.post after the context managed script ?
If yes
`async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:`
would be closed, and there won't be any reference for session